# CSS snap scroll does not work on custom sized child elements

Tags: css, scroll

I've put in the very basics of CSS snap scroll and can't get it to work. Any help is appretiated.

My code:

CSS:

```
#container {
scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
```

}

```
#section {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div> Random content </div>

      <section id="section">
        <div> Random content </div>
        <img> Random image </img>
      </section>

  </div>
```

I must mention that my section has a number of other properties applied:

```
 section {
    position: relative;
    height: 390px;
    width: 690px;
    object-fit: cover;
    }

section img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ian, it probably depends on the browser version you are using, but IE11, Edge, Safari might need a vendor prefix (-ms-.... and -webkit-...) in front of the property. Check [MDN: scroll-snap-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) (near the end of the page)